# How to transfer data between an Activity and a View class?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-view

I want to transfer 2 `float` values and 1 `boolean` value from my `MainActivity` class to `MyCanvas` class (which is a class extends View)? Is this possible?

I know this a newbie question, but everything that I found told to use `Intent` and `Bundle`, or to use only `Bundle.setArguments()`, but apparently, none of them work for a View class.

Thank you.

**EDIT 1**

This is my `MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MyCanvas myCanvas;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myCanvas = (MyCanvas) findViewById(R.id.canvas);
    }

    public void btnCalcularOnClick(View v) {

        TextView xResultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xResultado);
        TextView yResultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yResultado);

        EditText txtX = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtX);
        EditText txtY = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtY);

        //Comeco da Matematica

        float x = Float.parseFloat(txtX.getText().toString());
        float y = Float.parseFloat(txtY.getText().toString());

        float xResult = 5 * x;
        float yResult = 35 * y;

        boolean buttonState = true;
    }
}
```

`MyCanvas` class is like that

```
public class MyCanvas extends View {
    Paint myPaint;

    public MyCanvas(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        myPaint = new Paint();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas myCanvas) {
        super.onDraw(myCanvas);
        myPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        myPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);

        float cx, cy;
        boolean buttonState2;
    }
}
```

In this case, I want to transfer:

- `xResult` (MainActivity) -> `cx` (MyCanvas)
- `yResult` (MainActivity) -> `cy` (MyCanvas)
- `buttonState` (Main Activity) -> `buttonState2` (myCanvas)

Comment: Mycanvass class object you are creating inside Mainactivity?

Comment: No, MyCanvas is a different java file. I will edit with a code example.

Comment: maybe use setters getters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setters` to set the desired values in your `MyCanvas` class.

Create methods in your `MyCanvas` class like this.

```
public class MyCanvas extends View {

    private float cx, cy;
    private boolean buttonState2;

    ...

    public void setResults(float xResult, float yResult) {
        cx = xResult;
        cy = yResult;
    }

    public void setButtonState(boolean state) {
        buttonState2 = state;
    }
}
```

Then in your activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MyCanvas myCanvas;

    ...

    public void btnCalcularOnClick(View v){

        TextView xResultado = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.xResultado);
        TextView yResultado = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yResultado);

        EditText txtX= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtX);
        EditText txtY= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtY);

        //Comeco da Matematica

        float x = Float.parseFloat(txtX.getText().toString());
        float y = Float.parseFloat(txtY.getText().toString());

        float xResult = 5 * x;
        float yResult = 35 * y;

        boolean buttonState = true

        myCanvas.setResults(xResult, yResult);
        myCanvas.setButtonState(buttonState);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you man, that worked very well. The way you did it, it looks like it was so simple and I have never thought on this way, but really really thank you.

Comment: @AndBraz No worries, happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Create static variable and use it in your MyCanvas class.

In MainActvity:-

```
    public static float var1 = 1.0f;
    public static float var2 = 2.0f;
    public static boolean var3 = true;
```

And in your MyCanvas class:-

```
    private float var1InCanvas = MainActivity.var1;
    private float var2InCanvas = MainActivity.var2;
    private float var3inCanvas = MainActivity.var3;
```

Comment: Using static variables in activities to pass values is a bad practice.